# odbc connection for PL/SQL

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I'm using PL/sql developer to create `table.i` used conncetion codings like

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:test") 
ps = con.createStatement();

SQL_Str="Select * from dhanu_demo where uname like ('" + UName +"')"
rs=ps.executeQuery(SQL_Str);

rs.next();
dbusername=rs.getString(1).toString();
dbpassword=rs.getString(2).toString();
```

now i want to create dsn name through

controlpanal->performance&maintannence->datasource->system domain->?

i dunno which driver i need to select here. can anyone tell me. how to connect my jsf page to PL/SQL database??

Answer (score 0):

For your way of connecting there is no need to create dsn. because it uses the type 4 driver from oracle. Moreover to interact with database in jsf 
Check out the following link http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-jdbc-integration-example/